# How to restart/resume my background activity?

Tags: android

I have activity A which is activited by receiver B when new sms comes.
suppose I started activity by clicking on app icon and it starts activity A.
now I am pressing HOME key in my activity goes in background.
now if any sms comes than i want to start that old activity first or finish that old activity.

following is my code to call activity A  from receiver B:

```
 Intent intentSms = new Intent(context, A.class);
 intentSms.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intentSms);
```

can i do it ? 
if any body knows please reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

finish Activity A on `onUserLeaveHint()` because this method  called before `onPause()` if user press home button
In Activity A :

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {


    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    this.finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onResume function.

```
       @Override
   protected void onResume() 
       {
       super.onResume();
       }
```

Check if it works. onResume is called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.
Always followed by onPause().